# Pandas assign value from one member of group to all other members

Tags: python, pandas

I've searched for this but still can't get my head round groups, so...

The data (`dataFrame`) look something like this (`*` indicates desired output):

```
   id  parentid page_number is_critical_page page_number_of_critical* page_numbers_not_critical*
    0   1  1  1 True   1   2,3,4,5
    1   2  1  2 False  1   2,3,4,5
    2   3  1  3 False  1   2,3,4,5
    3   4  1  4 False  1   2,3,4,5
    4   5  1  5 False  1   2,3,4,5
    5   6  2  1 False  2   1,3
    6   7  2  2 True   2   1,3
    7   8  2  3 False  2   1,3
    8   9  3  1 False  -1  1
    9   10 4  1 True   1  -1
```

I want to:

1. Group rows by `parentid`:

   ```
   dgroups=dataFrame.groupby('parentid')
   ```
2. Apply arbitrary operations to groups:

   ```
   def func(grp):
       grp['has_critical_page'] = grp['is_critical_page'].sum()>0 # simple operation
       ### Apply operation here to generate:
       ### ?? grp['page_number_of_critical*'] = ... ??  # is a scalar
       ### ?? grp['page_numbers_not_critical'] = ... ?? # is a list
       return grp

   dgroups.apply(func)

   print dgroups.describe()
   ```

The `-1`'s are for N/As - could be a `NaN`, `None`, `-99` or any other special value.

I am not sure whether to use `apply`, `transform`, `filter` etc., or whether to apply(..) `func` to the rows of `dataFrame` or to those of the groups.

Trying to avoid for loops of course.... Thanks!

PS Bonus points for how to handle multiple hits of `is_critical_page` within the group...

Comment: PPS Not sure how to format the data table...

Comment: Thanks to whoever fixed the table...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the way is by creating the dictionary and mapping it, you can convert the page_number to strings and then join them while creating a dictionary and then map the dictionary i.e

```
df['page_number'] = df['page_number'].astype(str)
critical_pages=df[df.is_critical_page]
not_critical_pages=df[~df.is_critical_page]

not_critical_pages = not_critical_pages.groupby('parentid')['page_number'].apply(','.join).to_dict()
critical_pages = critical_pages.groupby('parentid')['page_number'].apply(','.join).to_dict()

df['page_number_of_critical*'] = df['parentid'].map(critical_pages)
df['not_page_number_of_critical*'] = df['parentid'].map(not_critical_pages)
```

Output :

```
   id  parentid page_number  is_critical_page page_number_of_critical*  \
0   1         1           1              True                        1   
1   2         1           2             False                        1   
2   3         1           3             False                        1   
3   4         1           4             False                        1   
4   5         1           5             False                        1   
5   6         2           1             False                        2   
6   7         2           2              True                        2   
7   8         2           3             False                        2   
8   9         3           1             False                      NaN   
9  10         4           1              True                        1   

  not_page_number_of_critical*  
0                      2,3,4,5  
1                      2,3,4,5  
2                      2,3,4,5  
3                      2,3,4,5  
4                      2,3,4,5  
5                          1,3  
6                          1,3  
7                          1,3  
8                            1  
9                          NaN
```

You can use `fillna` to fill it with values you want.

You can also use apply i.e

```
df['page_number'] = df['page_number'].astype(str)

crn_pages = df.groupby(['parentid','is_critical_page'])['page_number'].apply(','.join).to_dict()

df['page_number_of_critical*'] = df.apply(lambda x: crn_pages[x['parentid'],True] if (x['parentid'],True) in crn_pages else -1 ,axis=1)
df['not_page_number_of_critical*'] = df.apply(lambda x: crn_pages[x['parentid'],False] if (x['parentid'],False) in crn_pages else -1 ,axis=1)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Glad to help @jtlz2.